# ViewModel LiveData Emit isn't work properly in Android

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-livedata

In a part of the tutorial, I got the values of a list from the server using LiveDataScope and emit it and it works fine.

Now I want to refresh the list again with SwipeRefreshLayout but I don't know how to do it.

Actually I want to reuse liveDataScope code to refresh the list.

I read android docs about liveDataScope, If I understand correctly If liveData completed successfully, it doesn't restart.

In this case I don't know exactly what to do.

**ViewModel :**

```
val distanceLiveData: LiveData<List<Distance>>
 = liveData(coroutineExceptionHandler) {
            val distanceList = distanceRepository.getDistanceList()
            emit(distanceList)
        }
```

**Fragment :**

```
    distanceViewModel.distanceLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        it?.let {
            adapter.submitList(it as ArrayList<Distance>)
            adapter.submitList(it)
            binding.recyclerViewDistance.adapter = adapter
        }
    }

binding.swipeRefreshLayoutDistance.setOnRefreshListener {
    //I need to refresh list here
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your viewmodel you should expose a method to update livedata like:

```
private val _distanceLiveData = MutableLiveData<List<Distance>>()
val distanceLiveData: LiveData<List<Distance>> = _distanceLiveData
    
init {
    getDistanceList()
}        

 fun getDistanceList(){
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val distanceList = distanceRepository.getDistanceList()
            _distanceLiveData.value = distanceList
        }
    }
```

then in your fragment call method to update livedata

```
        distanceViewModel.distanceLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            it?.let {
                adapter.submitList(it as ArrayList<Distance>)
                adapter.submitList(it)
                binding.recyclerViewDistance.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
    
    binding.swipeRefreshLayoutDistance.setOnRefreshListener {
        distanceViewModel.getDistanceList()
    }
```

Comment: Your solution is correct but I want to get the list using LiveDataScope

Comment: Tell me exactly which specific usecase you wanna handle using liveData builder?

Comment: I want to use LiveData with coroutines

Comment: You can use liveData with coroutines in liveData builder but in your usecase you can't reuse it, instead use `viewModelScope`

Comment: So Where is LiveDataScope used?

Comment: `viewModelScope` is used for coroutines handling instead of liveData builder

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254846/discussion-between-asad-mahmood-and-nima-khalili).

Comment: Why do you specifically want to use the live data scope? What you are describing is simply not possible.

Comment: @Tenfour04 I thought it's necessary because I read in docs : If LiveDataScope is canceled before completion, it is restarted if the LiveData becomes active again but I think It's not necessary in this case.

Comment: The LifeDataScope is a piece of a publicly unnamed subclass of LiveData that only exists publicly as part of the `liveData { }` coroutine-based LiveData builder function. It's an internal piece of how that specific type of LiveData works. Since that type of LiveData is not applicable to cases where you need to update a LiveData externally, it is irrelevant to your problem. MutableLiveData is the right tool for an externally updated LiveData.